# Central limit theorem assignment

Tags: statistics

What does it mean if my assignments askes "state the central limit theorem" I am unsure If it is supposed to be a series of numbers or a statement.

Comment: What does "theorem" mean to you?

Comment: Typically they are asking you to state the assumptions and the implication of those assumptions. Think about what must be true for the clt to hold and then what does the clt tell

Comment: "State the central limit theorem" literally means what you think it means. Find the statement of the theorem in your notes or text, then write it down.

Comment: Try to understand the theorem before writing it down